# Javascript : Get data through ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

It may be possible this question has been posted so many times.But i didn't get answer from those one.I have passed url in Ajax call and i want whatever i'm getting from database through the query,get in success method of ajax request.But somehow i didn't get this.

Ajax call method:

```
function validateAmount() {
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
    // alert(amount);
    // var y = x.value;
    $.ajax({
        url : "{{url('getAmount')}}",
        type : "GET",
        async : false,
        dataType : "json",
        success : function (result) {
            alert();
        }
    });
}
```

and database query:

And this is what i want to return

```
public function getAmount(){
    $user_id = session('user_id');
    $res = DB::table('table_name')->where(['user_id'=>$user_id])->first();
    return $res;
}
```

And one more thing,when i simply echo string in getAmount method ,ajax call get succeed but when i try to access the data through query,i'm getting fail.

Please help me to get this.
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You obviosly have some error in query. Check logs and fix it.

Comment: You're not returning JSON from your PHP as your jQuery AJAX call is expecting. Try `return json_encode($res);`. Also, remove `async: false`. It's incredibly bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for answering.I got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First** : Remove the `async: false` as Rory mentioned in the comments.

**Second:** For the ajax you have to use the `echo json_encode($my_data_array);`

**Third:** Dont use `alert` rather use `console.log(result)` to view your data.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Collection::toJson()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-tojson) method to transform you collection to json string:

```
$res = DB::table('table_name')->where('user_id', $user_id)->first();
return $res->toJson();
```

[Collection::toArray()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-toarray) works too